# Link to year/month page on Facebook timeline view

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there a way to create a link to a particular month/year within the timeline view (i.e. an anchor format of some kind)?

Or a way to generate a link via the graph API?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it

`http://www.facebook.com/<username>/timeline/2012/8`

Comment: After years since you posted this answer .. i wanna say to you THANKS :) i've been searching for this cause i've been sick of scroll down ^_^